# Find if field="x" or noting? mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

How would I find records where:

```
"key1"="val1" and

1) if "key2" exists ->"key2"="val2"
2) if "key2" doesn't exist ignore it in search. Use only "key1"="val1"
```

Input data:

```
{id:1, key1: A}
{id:2, key1: B, key2: D}
{id:3, key1: B, key2: C}
{id:4, key1: B}
```

Query find key1=B, key2=C (if exists):

```
.find({'key1':B, {'key2':$exists{....}}})?
```

Result should be:

```
[{id:3...},{id:4...}]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're on a mongo version that supports it, you can use the `$in` operator with null: `{ key1: val1, key2: {$in: [val2, null] }}`. (I know 3.6 supports this, but I'm unsure of when it got added in)

You can also use the $or operator: `{key1: val1, $or: [{key2: val2}, {key2: {$exists: false}]}`

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in